# Shorten Code by accessing Dictionary with if

Tags: c#, dictionary, if-statement

I have the following code

```
Dictionary<string, string> changesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
if (changesDictionary.ContainsKey("field1"))
{
    resultObject.field1 = changesDictionary["field1"];
}
if (changesDictionary.ContainsKey("field2"))
{
    resultObject.field2 = changesDictionary["field2"];
}
if (changesDictionary.ContainsKey("field3"))
{
    resultObject.field3 = changesDictionary["field3"];
}
```

which has 4 lines for a potential assignment. I'm wondering if there is a way to write it shorter.

I've tried the ternary operator which makes one line but it's harder to read.

```
resultObject.field1 = changesDictionary.ContainsKey("field1") ? changesDictionary["field1"] : resultObject.field1;
```

Comment: Consider using `TryGetValue` instead of `ContainsKey`, to avoid unnecessary hash lookups.

Comment: @mjwills That would make this code slightly more verbose though as you need to introduce another variable to hold the intermediate value.

Comment: @DavidG C# has `out var` now, so no.

Comment: @canton7 That is still creating another variable.

Comment: `if (changesDictionary.TryGetValue("field1", out var field1)) { resultObject.field1 = field1; }` isn't more verbose, at least to me? It isn't any less verbose however...

Comment: @canton7 It's arguably less readable because of the added out variable. The real point I'm trying to make is that this question is opinion based...

Answer (score 4):

You could always do something like this. It's more verbose to start, but if you have lots of properties then it might pay off:

```
var fields = new (string key, Action<ResultObject, string> setter)[]
{
    ("field1", (x, val) => x.field1 = val),
    ("field2", (x, val) => x.field2 = val),
    ("field3", (x, val) => x.field3 = val),
};

foreach (var (key, setter) in fields)
{
    if (changesDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var field))
    {
        setter(resultObject, field);
    }
}
```

Another option is something like this:

```
// A local function which captures 'resultObject' and 'changesDictionary'
void Set(string key, Action<ResultObject, string> setter)
{
    if (changesDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var field))
    {
         setter(resultObject, field);
    }
}

Set("field1", (x, val) => x.field1 = val);
Set("field2", (x, val) => x.field2 = val);
Set("field3", (x, val) => x.field3 = val);
```

Otherwise, if you're prepared to change your style slightly, you can do this:

```
if (changesDictionary.TryGetValue("field1", out var field1)) resultObject.field1 = field1;
if (changesDictionary.TryGetValue("field2", out var field2)) resultObject.field2 = field2;
if (changesDictionary.TryGetValue("field3", out var field3)) resultObject.field1 = field3;
```

Comment: Why do you need the `ResultObject` type parameter?

Comment: @vc74 so I can declare a lambda which looks like `(x, val) => x.field1 = val` rather than `val => resultObject.field1 = val`. It's ever so slightly terser (IMO), and it lets the compiler re-use the same delegate instance for multiple `resultObject` instances, which makes it slightly cheaper.

Comment: But you know it's `resultObject` that is going to be updated, there's no need to pass it to the action.

Comment: @vc74 you are correct, but see the two points I made in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Using a local function:

```
void SetField(string fieldName, Action<string> updater)
{
    if (changesDictionary.TryGetValue(fieldName, out string fieldValue))
    {
        updater(fieldValue);
    }
}

SetField("field1", f => resultObject.field1 = f);
SetField("field2", f => resultObject.field2 = f);
SetField("field3", f => resultObject.field3 = f);
```

Price to pay = readability--

Line count = 11 instead of 13

Using a local function + reflection (provided fieldx are public properties):

```
void SetField(string fieldName)
{
    if (changesDictionary.TryGetValue(fieldName, out string fieldValue))
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = resultObject.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(resultObject, fieldValue);
    }
}

SetField("field1");
SetField("field2");
SetField("field3");
```

Price to pay = performance--

Line count = 12 instead of 13, but if you have 20 fields to update:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
{
    SetField($"field{i}");
}
```

Much shorter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (given the lowercase names for the `field` fields) that `field1`, `field2` and `field3` are actually fields rather than properties, then you can write a local function to simplify the code as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, string> changesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

void update(ref string field, string key)
{
    if (changesDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
        field = value;
}

update(ref resultObject.field1, "field1");
update(ref resultObject.field2, "field1");
update(ref resultObject.field3, "field1");
```

Note that will NOT work if `field1` etc are actually properties, because of course you can't use `ref` with a property.

Comment: I mean yes, but why? This is taking a simple bit of code and making it more complicated. Not sure why everyone is over complicating this :)

Comment: @DavidG If you're updating a LOT of fields (rather than just 3) then this is likely to make it a lot more readable.

Comment: Yes, but it really looks like OP is updating 3 or 4, and none of these posts actually answer the question being asked which is to shorten the code.

Comment: No, you can't do that simplification. If `key` doesn't exist in `changesDictionary` then it will set the field to `null` instead of leaving it at its current value.

Comment: Yeah I just realised that can't be simplified - so I removed those edits.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static TValue GetOrDefault<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue defaultValue)
    {
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            return value;

        return defaultValue;
    }
}

. . .

resultObject.field1 = changesDictionary.GetOrDefault("field1", resultObject.field1);
resultObject.field2 = changesDictionary.GetOrDefault("field2", resultObject.field2);
resultObject.field3 = changesDictionary.GetOrDefault("field3", resultObject.field3);
```

Answer (score -1):

If your object has FIELDS not PROPERTIES, u can use just TryGetValue to field like this

```
changesDictionary.TryGetValue(nameof(ResultObject.field1), out resultObject.field1);
```

full example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp27
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var resultObject = new ResultObject();
            var changesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            changesDictionary.Add(nameof(ResultObject.field1), "q1");
            changesDictionary.Add(nameof(ResultObject.field2), "q2");
            changesDictionary.Add(nameof(ResultObject.field3), "q3");
            changesDictionary.Add(nameof(ResultObject.field4), "q4");

            changesDictionary.TryGetValue(nameof(ResultObject.field1), out resultObject.field1);
            changesDictionary.TryGetValue(nameof(ResultObject.field2), out resultObject.field2);
            changesDictionary.TryGetValue(nameof(ResultObject.field3), out resultObject.field3);
            changesDictionary.TryGetValue(nameof(ResultObject.field4), out resultObject.field4);

            Console.WriteLine(resultObject.field1);
            Console.WriteLine(resultObject.field2);
            Console.WriteLine(resultObject.field3);
            Console.WriteLine(resultObject.field4);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public class ResultObject
        {
            public string field1;
            public string field2;
            public string field3;
            public string field4;
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
q1
q2
q3
q4
```

Comment: This is wrong. This sets `resultObject.field1` to `null` if "field" doesn't appear in `changesDictionary`. The OP's code leaves it at its original value.

Comment: I would have liked a description of what is going on here too, code dump answers are considered low quality.